# I want to match this two image by RGB pixel in Matlab..I guess my code is ok..but it's not working

Tags: matlab

Here I am using main image ''cricketteam.jpg' and cropped a portion of it named 'musfiq.jpg'. But from my code, I can't even match a single pixel though they are same. What is the problem?

Here is my code:

```
function imageMatch
    i1=imread('cricketteam.jpg');
    [y,x,d]=size(i1);
    m=imread('musfiq.jpg');
    [y1,x1,d]=size(m);
    x2=1;
    y2=1;
    row_match=0;
    flag_y=0;
    cx=1;
    xc=1;
    xc1=1;


s_loop=x-x1;

s_loop= s_loop+1;
for i=1:y
   cx=xc;

    for j=cx:x


        if j==s_loop && row_match==0
            break;
        end
        f=impixel(m,x2,y2);

        ma=impixel(i1,j,i);

        end
        if isequal(f,ma)==1

             if  row_match == 0
                xc=cx;
             end
            row_match=row_match+1;
            x2=x2+1;
        else

              flag_y=0;
              row_match=0;
              y2=1;
              x2=1;

        end
        if row_match==x1
              flag_y=flag_y+1;
              row_match=0;
              y2=y2+1;
              x2=1;
              break;
        end

    end

    if  flag_y==y1
        disp('Image Matched')
        break;
    end
end

end
```

Here is **cricketteam.jpg** :[image]

Here is the portion **musfiq.jpg** :

[image]

Comment: they're jpegs. it's a lossy format. just because two pixels LOOK the same to you doesn't mean they ARE the same. one could be rgb(255,0,0) and the other could be rgb(254,1,0) or whatever. very close, but definitely not the same. when you extracted your snippet and re-compressed it to another jpg, pretty much all of the pixels are going to be slightly different due to the jpeg compression.

Comment: thanks...what can I do to get exactly same pixels as the original? what format it should be?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

Jpeg images include jpeg compression, and therefore the patch which you are looking for is not going to appear as-is in the image.
Instead, you can look for the location of the patch which maximizes the [normalized cross correlation (NCC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation#Normalized_cross-correlation) between the images. The NCC is a measure which evaluates the level of similarity between two patches.
In order to do so, use MATLAB's [normxcorr2](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/normxcorr2.html) function.

**Code**

```
%reads images
I = rgb2gray(imread('team.jpg')); 
template = rgb2gray(imread('p.jpg')); 
[h,w]=size(template);

%calculate the ncc at each pixel
c = normxcorr2(template,I);

%finds the maximal ncc pixel
[y, x] = find(c==max(c(:)));

%extracts the relevant patch
yoffSet = ypeak-size(template,1);
xoffSet = xpeak-size(template,2);
patch = I(y-h+1:y,x-w+1:x);
```

**Result**

numeric result:

```
C(y,x) = 0.9992 %ncc result (complete match is 1)
[y, x]= 84 342 %most suitable patch center
```

Image output:

```
%display the original image with the found patch
hFig = figure;
hAx  = axes;
imshow(I,'Parent', hAx);
imrect(hAx, [xoffSet+1, yoffSet+1, size(template,2), size(template,1)]);
```

[image]